# Ramda: convert key value array to object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm using `Ramda` to sort a normalized model object by key. Firstly I convert to key|value pairs (equivalent of `Object.entries`), and sort by the first value using `R.head` (the `key` value when in pairs)

I want to convert the resulting sorted array of pairs to an array of objects - in the example code I'm using ES6+ `map` and `array destructuring`

```js
const data = {
  2: {name: 'two'},
  1: {name: 'one'}
}

const sortByKey = R.compose(R.sortBy(R.head), R.toPairs);
const sortedPairs = sortByKey(data)
console.log(sortedPairs)
// [["1",{"name":"one"}],["2",{"name":"two"}]]

const objs = sortedPairs.map(([key, value]) => {
  return {[key]: value}
})
console.log(objs)
// [{"1":{"name":"one"}},{"2":{"name":"two"}}]
```

The part I can't find a `Ramda` function for is

```
const objs = sortedPairs.map(([key, value]) => {
  return {[key]: value}
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if intentional, but object keys are always strings. So when you `sortByKey` with `data = {2: {name: "two"}, 12: {name: "twelve"}}`, the resulting `sortedPairs` will be `[["12", {name: "twelve"}], ["2", {name: "two"}]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use R.map with applied R.objOf to convert an array of pairs ([key, value]) to an array objects

```js
const { compose, map, apply, objOf, sortBy, head, toPairs } = R

const sortByKey = compose(sortBy(head), toPairs)
const arrayFromPairs = map(apply(objOf))

const data = {
  2: {name: 'two'},
  1: {name: 'one'}
}

const result = arrayFromPairs(sortByKey(data))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or of course just `const sortByKey = compose (map (apply (objOf)), sortBy (head), toPairs)` ... `const result = sortByKey (data)`.  I don't see much use for the intermediate structure.

Comment: Same here (see edits). However, for the sake of the answer I've decided to leave it separated.

Comment: In its current form `arrayFromPairs` can be reused - which is what I was looking for

Comment: @Drenal: Sure.  If you have that intermediate structure, then `arrayFromPairs` is certainly useful.  I just see little use for that structure.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with that answer -- there never is from OriDrori! -- but I was pointing out what I see as a possible simplification.

Comment: I'll blush under my mask :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compose(fromPairs, of)` to create an object from a single pair.

```js
const fromPair = compose(fromPairs, of);
fromPair(["a", 1]);
//=> {"a": 1}
```

```js
const { compose, fromPairs, head, map, of, sortBy, toPairs } = R;

const sortByKey = compose(sortBy(head), toPairs);
const fromPair = compose(fromPairs, of);
const arrayFromPairs = map(fromPair);

const data = {
  2: {name: 'two'},
  1: {name: 'one'},
};

const sortedPairs = sortByKey(data);
const objs = arrayFromPairs(sortedPairs);
console.log(objs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```